# WPF Live Charts - XAML code not linking to C# code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, livecharts

I'm struggling with live charts. I'm using WPF.

I want to build a bar chart that displays the number of members in a Karate Club by belt color. One of my learning projects.

Following their docs: 
https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/wpf/Basic%20Column

I am getting an error in xaml:

d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:Charts}"
'The name "Charts" does not exist in namespace "clr-namespace:KarateClub" '

and

LabelFormatter="{Binding Formatter}"
'Method Formatter not found in type Charts'

If I remove the DataContext code the graph displays but it doesn't use any of my values.
I must be missing how to link the XAML code to the C# code...?
Have I got the class/namespace path wrong?

My XAML Code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="KarateClub.Charts"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:KarateClub"
             xmlns:lvc="clr-namespace:LiveCharts.Wpf;assembly=LiveCharts.Wpf"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="400" d:DesignWidth="1000" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:Charts}" >

    <Grid Background="White" Width="1000" Height="550">
        <Grid Background="White" Margin="33,45,239,170">
            <lvc:CartesianChart Series="{Binding SeriesCollection}" LegendLocation="Left">
                <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
                    <lvc:Axis Title="Belts" Labels="{Binding Labels}"></lvc:Axis>
                </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
                <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
                    <lvc:Axis Title="Members" LabelFormatter="{Binding Formatter}"></lvc:Axis>
                </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
            </lvc:CartesianChart>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

My C# Code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using LiveCharts;
using LiveCharts.Wpf;

namespace KarateClub
{
    public partial class Charts : UserControl
    {

        public SeriesCollection SeriesCollection { get; set; }
        public string[] Labels { get; set; }
        public Func<double, string> Formatter { get; set; }


        public Charts()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            SeriesCollection = new SeriesCollection
            {
                new ColumnSeries
                {
                    Title = "2020",
                    Values = new ChartValues<double> { 1, 5, 3, 5, 7, 3, 9, 2, 3 }
                }
            };

            Labels = new[] { "White", "Yellow", "Orange", "Green", "Blue", "Purple", "Brown", "Red", "Black" };
            Formatter = value => value.ToString("N");

            DataContext = this;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently using a design-time instance of `Charts`, which is generated by the designer. This instance is auto-generated and doesn't contain any data. This is the default behavior, which is controlled by the `IsDesignTimeCreatable` property of the markup extension `DesignInstanceExtension`. By default `IsDesignTimeCreatable` returns `false`, which directs the designer to create a fake instance using reflection (bypassing any constructor).

To use a design-time instance of the specified type which is properly constructed, you have to set this property explicitly to `true`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="KarateClub.Charts"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:KarateClub"
             d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:Charts, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}" >
  ...
</UserControl>
```

Now the designer will create an instance using the constructor instead of using reflection.

Apparently this Blend design-time attributes are not well documented. To learn more see [Microsoft Docs: Design-Time Attributes in the Silverlight Designer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/silverlight/dotnet-windows-silverlight/ff602277%28v%3Dvs.95%29)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have included IsDesignTimeCreatable=True as per your advice. However, the datacontect is still highlighted with the error "The name "Charts" does not exist in namespace "clr-namespace:KarateClub" '

Comment: Have you tried to rebuild the project? From what I see the namespace is correct and everything should work. If rebuilding doesn't fix it, remove the complete namespace import from the XAML file and let Visual Studio add it for you. Restarting VS might also help in case the designer has crashed.

Comment: Yes, a rebuild fixed it! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The example you are following does not say `d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:Charts}"`.

it says `d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:BasicColumn}"`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The reason I put charts is that "Basic Column" is the class name in their example and my class name is Charts. I tried changing it but I get the same error.  'The name "BasicColumn" does not exist in namespace "clr-namespace:KarateClub" '